# C# can't add dynamically panel

Tags: c#, panel

I try to add a panel to Form, but it never appears. But When I change its type e.g. on TextBox it apears. Anyone know why?

```
HidePanel = new Panel();
HidePanel.ForeColor = Color.Red;
HidePanel.BackColor = Color.Green;//Form.BackColor;
HidePanel.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(531, 181); 
HidePanel.Name = "HidePanel";
HidePanel.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(200, 100); 
HidePanel.Visible = true;
HidePanel.TabIndex = 12;
HidePanel.BringToFront();
Form.Controls.Add(HidePanel);
```

Comment: a bit more context would be needed, anyway, a basic tutorial on winforms should do the job...

Answer (score 1):

you used Form and it's not true, you should use **this** instead of Form, try this code.

```
HidePanel = new Panel();
HidePanel.ForeColor = Color.Red;
HidePanel.BackColor = Color.Green;//Form.BackColor;
HidePanel.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(531, 181); 
HidePanel.Name = "HidePanel";
HidePanel.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(200, 100); 
HidePanel.Visible = true;
HidePanel.TabIndex = 12;
HidePanel.BringToFront();
this.Controls.Add(HidePanel);
```

---

update:

```
    Form2 frm = new Form2();
    Panel HidePanel = new Panel();
    HidePanel.ForeColor = Color.Red;
    HidePanel.BackColor = Color.Green;//Form.BackColor;
    HidePanel.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(531, 181);
    HidePanel.Name = "HidePanel";
    HidePanel.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(200, 100);
    HidePanel.Visible = true;
    HidePanel.TabIndex = 12;
    HidePanel.BringToFront();
    frm.Controls.Add(HidePanel);
    frm.Show();
```

---

I put this code in click event of button1, which declared in form1.

Comment: I mean replace this.Controls.Add instead of Form.Controls.Add .

Comment: just edit your answer if needed :) it actually depends on context is he should use this. or maybe some other variable :P

Comment: I can't use 'this' because it is different class and I pass to it my Form. So I use objcet Form. This can't be reason of that, because when i change type on TextBox, it apperas no my form.

Comment: Then use that object with reference or declare object globally inside a class.

Comment: HidePanel is static global element of that class

Comment: No, it has its default color. I have already told that when I chagne type of HidePanel to TextBox it appears on the top of the Form, but Panel does not. I set Red and Green colors to see high contrast with everything arround it.

Comment: try to change use left and top instead of location, HidePanel.Left = 0; HidePanel.Top = 0, probably this will solve problem.

Comment: ok I checked code few time it works correctly on my computer, I think the problem is about your form, please tell me where did you declared your form. and I will update codes above for you please check it, and use this code.

Comment: I created my form using Visual Studio Designer. So it created form's class and every control on it.

Comment: EDIT:
I did local declaration of Panel and suddenly it appeared on the form. Then I went back to global static declaration and it stands well. I don't know why compiler does such things... Thank you for your help